# How to show all row operations when doing RREF in a LaTeX document

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, arrows

I am looking to format my RREF calculations in a LaTeX document to look like this with all 3-row operations shown. All the posts on Stack and the overleaf page only allow for 2 equations shown or multiple equations with multiple arrows. I would like 1 arrow and 3 equations.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Mico I have tried this 

\xrightarrow[ r_1+3r_3]{ r_2+5r_3}

I also tried the " \\" after the second transformation but it did not work, I also tried adding another [] and {} and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The macro `\xrightarrow` can take both subscript and superscript arguments. To create a line break in the superscript material, encase it in a `\substack` wrapper directive. Both `\xrightarrow` and `\substack` are directives provided by the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for \xrightarrow and \substack macros
\begin{document}
\[
\xrightarrow[R_1(-3)+R_4]{%
   \substack{R_1(3)+R_3 \\
             R_1(2)+R_3}}
\]
\end{document}
```